# Ho to set a default query parameter in cakephp 3.6?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a classical index page with a form where I can filter my records.

One of my fields is `year`. Let's say that I want the records to be pre-filtered by current year when the user first visit the page (i.e. when the query string is empty)

**what have I done:**

in my controller I did something like this

```
if(empty($this->request->query))
{
    $this->request->query['year'] =  date('Y');
}
```

and then with the help of friendsofcake/search plugig:

```
$this->MyTable->find('search', [
    'search' => $this->request->getQuery()
]);
```

In this way the records are filtered and the form is pre compiled with the current year since in my view I have

```
'valueSources' => 'query'
```

Now with cake 3.6 direct modification of the query is deprecated (see [**this**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/11966) issue I opened). In fact I get deprecation warnings when I try to change the query array.

**My question:**

So I want to know what is the best way to achieve the same behavior without getting warnings. I would also like to know if and why my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In controller:

```
$searchValues = $this->request->getQueryParams() ?: ['year' => date('Y')];
$this->MyTable->find('search', [
    'search' => $searchValues
]);
$this->set(compact('searchValues'));
```

In template:

```
$this->Form->create(['schema' => [], 'defaults' => $searchValues]);
```

Ideally you would also set proper values in `schema` as shown here https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/class-Cake.View.Form.ArrayContext.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I tell the form to use MyTable schema?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (not tested):

```
$this->setRequest($this->getRequest()->withQueryParams([
    'year' => date('Y'),
]);
```

Comment: this will reset the whole query string. But of course you can pass a merged array to the same method and it works. But I'm more interested in knowing if there is a better approach